# how do I get the form data in a javascript object so I can send it as the data parameter of an $.ajax call

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to return json after form.submit()?

---

```
 <form id="NotificationForm" action="<%=Url.Action("Edit",new{Action="Edit"}) %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit='getJsonRequestAfterSubmittingForm(this); return false;'>
      <%Html.RenderPartial("IndexDetails", Model);%>
     </form>

 $.ajax({
        url: '<%=Url.Action("Edit","Notification") %>',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $("#NotificationForm").submit(),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(result) {
            if (result.Result == true) {
                alert("ghjghsgd");
            }
        },
        error: function(request, status, error) {
            $("#NotSelectedList").html("Error: " & request.responseText);
        }

    });
```

Comment: -1.  Please try to add more detail to your question.  If you expect people to spend more than 10 seconds answering, you should spend at least a few minutes explaining your problem in more detail.

Comment: I deleted my answer. Your actual question is: how do I get the form data in a javascript object so I can send it as the data parameter of an $.ajax call.

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you're actually looking for is not the Submit method, but how to serialise the form data to a json object. To do this you have to use a helper method like here: [Serialize form to JSON](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/serialize-form-to-json/)

Use this instead of running the submit() method, and you'll be fine.
Also, this question is a duplicate of this (even though the question text, and the title are completely misleading): [Serialize form to JSON with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/serialize-form-to-json-with-jquery)

Posting the jQuery extender, just in case, so that it doesn't get lost :)

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
   var o = {};
   var a = this.serializeArray();
   $.each(a, function() {
       if (o[this.name]) {
           if (!o[this.name].push) {
               o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
           }
           o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
       } else {
           o[this.name] = this.value || '';
       }
   });
   return o;
};
```

After you have this in your page, you can update your ajax call with this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '<%=Url.Action("Edit","Notification") %>',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $("#NotificationForm").serializeObject(),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(result) {
            if (result.Result == true) {
                alert("ghjghsgd");
            }
        },
        error: function(request, status, error) {
            $("#NotSelectedList").html("Error: " & request.responseText);
        }

    });
```

**UPD:** If you want to POST the form, then get the response as a json object, and do another ajax call.. then you should look at the [jquery.form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). you will be able to post your form using an ajax call, then get the response, and run some js when it will return.

Comment: Is it possible to return json after the data: ("#NotificationForm").submit();

My aim here is to submit the form and retrieve json after the submission.  The part where I use ("#NotificationForm").submit(); is working fine, but it then falls in the error...why?

Comment: To be completely honest - looking at what you're trying to achieve here, you're just doing it wrong.. I think you should rethink your process there =/
I updated the post with some info that would help you anyway :)